# Can't rename a file in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have some image files that will keep the old name every time I rename it. VS Code is adding a "." to the beginning of each file, which makes it not recognize it as an image file. The file name is correct on my local storage, without the ".", but when I try and change it in VS Code it keeps the ".", whether I change it in local storage or in VS Code.

For example my file name is "brand-awareness.png" in my local file, but VS Code adds a "." to the beginning even if I change the name to something completely different like "tacos.png".